# Postgres BIGINT out of range

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

I'm discovering a new world with PostgreSQL but while transefering a Firebird 2.1 database to PostgreSQL 9.3 i've encountered folowing error

```
BIGINT out of range:
```

I've checked the Min and Max values from import statement and they fit in Bigint and could imported,  but the whole insert statement in the attachment gives me error. I've also reporduced the error in PGAdmin.

Table have following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(
  id integer NOT NULL 
  n0 bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  n1 bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  n2 bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  n3 bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  .
  .
  .
  n247 bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT SomeTable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

[File with  actual insert statement and table structure, also extracted values](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz6l2hs082CnOWVnc1g2OXExOEk/edit?usp=sharing)

Any suggestions ?

ACTUAL ERROR
ERROR:  bigint out of range
********* Error *********

ERROR: bigint out of range
SQL state: 22003

**UPDATE**
I`m using statements in this form

```
insert .... values ((1::int4),(2222222222::int8)....);
```

when changed it to

```
insert .... values (1,2222222222,....);
```

It works. 
It seems to me like a litle bug in Postgres.

**UPDATE**

The query is form from NPGSQL 2.0 prepared statement.
in version 2.1 the issue is fixed and works fine 
 [NPGSQL bug tracker with the issue](http://pgfoundry.org/tracker/?group_id=1000140&atid=590&func=detail&aid=1010543)

Comment: Could you post the exact error?

Comment: Please show the *complete, unaltered* insert statement that is failing. Also, are there any triggers/rules on the table you are inserting into?

Comment: sqlfidlle demo containing the error http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bafb9/1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This value in your [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bafb9/1) example is out of range :

```
select -9223372036854775808::int8;
ERROR:  bigint out of range
```

The problem is that it first tries to convert `9223372036854775808` to bigint to only then change its sign. It works if you do

```
select (-9223372036854775808)::bigint;
         int8         
----------------------
 -9223372036854775808
```

Comment: according documentation bigint is 

-9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807 and  9223372036854775808 should be valid value

Comment: @danisius And it is. __Read__ the answer

Comment: fianlly get it.Thanks